# Self-referencial (recursive) struct with no dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, struct, recursive-datastructures

I have a struct to represent an AST, and I'm on an embedded device, I have no malloc, everything should be either on stack or global.

So my struct;

```
/* AST Structre */
typedef struct ast {
    uint8_t type; /* This is the token value in grammar.h */

    /* Value of the token */
    union {
        double number;
        char literal;
    } value;

    struct ast *left; /* left hand side of the node */
    struct ast *right; /* right hand side of the node */
} ast_t;
```

My question is whats the best way to use recursive structs without malloc.

Comment: You can create a compile-time array, and have pointers to the different elements of the array.

Comment: An array; `ast_t mydata[12345];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create an array and initialize/assign as needed.

```
ast_t fred[] = { { 1, {2.0}, NULL,     &fred[1]}, 
                 { 3, {4.0}, &fred[0], NULL    } };
```

Call the `ast_t` functions `foo(fred);`.  Be sure to not call `free(fred)`.